# "Assigned To" field not available when creating a "Update a Record" Quick Action on task

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

i have created a new Action  **Edit** with Action Type as "Update a Record" on Task Object.

I want to add **"Assigned To"** field which is a lookup to User,Calendar in my layout of Edit.
But i don't see this field available in the palette , so that i can drag and drop to the Layout.

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Assigned To" is actually the `OwnerId` field. Unless a User either owns the Task record or is in the hierarchy above the existing Owner of the record, depending on your sharing model and a user's profile permissions, they're not going to be able to change ownership of a Task.